# Python: Do I have to use else statements (unless mandated by code)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I understand `if`, `else`, and `elif` statements. However, I am unsure of the best practice for their use with `return` in function blocks. What is the most Pythonic way to write if/else constructs with return blocks?

```
# Other's code:
def my_function():
    do = input("Enter 'n' to print 1 and any other key to print 2")
    if do == "n":
        print(1)
        return
    else:
        print("2")
        return

# My code:
def my_function():
    do = input("Enter 'n' to print 1 and any other key to print 2")
    if do == "n":
        print(1)
        return
    # Note that I do not use an else statement here
    print("2")
    return
```

Is there a *need* for an `else` (or `elif`) statement on the last line? I do not see the point of the one extra `else` (or `elif`) statement when I can just type my code after the `if` statement.

I'm also confused as I recently learnt that `else` statements can be paired with loops. (e.g. `for ... else ...`)

Comment: These are logically two completely different things.

In the first one, the code after `elif select == "s": ` only gets executed if select is not 'a', but 's'

In the second example, the code after `if select == "s": ` gets executed even select is 's' , no matter if it is also 'a'

You are right, in this scenario it probably won't make a difference. However, you should write the code such that it says what the function actually tries to achieve. THis depends on the problem.

Comment: @user3207838 what does that mean?

Comment: This means that in your example, it probably won't make a difference. But you have to understand that these two things are different from a logical point of view.

Comment: @user3207838 ok, I edited the last part. But, I meant do I *have* to put 'elif' or 'else' unless *absolutely* mandatory? (Like in this one, it isn't, but in some people's code I see they've used 'elif' and such even though it isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You codes aren't a good example for `elif` and `else`. But i will analyze your example firstly.

1. The first condition:

```
select = input("Enter 'a' to add, 's' to subtract, 'x' to exit: ")
if select == "a":
    # code
elif select == "s": 
    # code
elif select == "x": 
    return
```

You need least a `else` here. What happen, if the user enter a `y`?

Your code:

```
if select == "a":
    # code
if select == "s": 
    # code
if select == "x": 
    return
```

The 3 `if` conditions will be always checked . It's not efficiency in this case. And sometime it does a total different scenario.

I will write the code with `while` and `else` so:

```
while(True)
    select = input("Enter 'a' to add, 's' to subtract, 'x' to exit: ")
    if select == "a":
        # code
        break
    elif select == "s": 
        # code
        break
    elif select == "x": 
        return
    else:
        print "Input is invalid!"
```

2. The second condition is right. `else` is may be not necessary here. But it's better to write the code with `else` like that (It does the same task, but it's clearer):

```
if do == "n":
    print(1)
else:
    print("2")
return
```

*P/S: So you see: **`else` isn't useless**. Always try to check your code again and find a way to improve it.*

Comment: Ohhh, so:
1. It can be used for incorrect user input.
2. It's so that it's more efficient to cuz then it doesn't check the rest.
Right??

Comment: exactly. You got it

Comment: but then..should i use `try` `except` for bad user input or these kind of `else` statements when possible? I feel `try except` would be more maintainable/readable cuz it's obvious what is happening, or should i use these? (when possible)

Comment: It depends on your program. There isn't exception to catch, if the user enters a wrong input. You can only use `else` in this case.

Comment: Like i wrote, try to write more codes and improve them self. You will understand more. There are very many examples about `if`, `elif`, `else`, `try`, `except`, .... Sometime it's right for this case, but wrong for another case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need an example with real code. Let's use the one with `elif` and `else` first.

```
x = 0
if x == 0:
    print('x == 0')
    x = 1
elif x == 1:
    print('x == 1')
    x = 2
else:
    print('x is not 0 or 1')
```

This will print `x == 0`.

Now we'll look at the solution you prefer (and which you believe to be the same).

```
x = 0
if x == 0:
    print('x == 0')
    x = 1
if x == 1:
    print('x == 1')
    x = 2
print('x is not 0 or 1')
```

This will print `x == 0`, `x == 1` and `x is not 0 or 1`.

The usage of `elif` and `else` is not a question of programming style but programming logic.

Answer (score 0):

The two blocks of code are not equivalent:

In the first one, `select` only gets tested once if it is "a" (more efficient), and the `print` will **only** be executed if `select` is something other than a, s, or x.

```
select = input("Enter 'a' to add, 's' to subtract, 'x' to exit: ")
if select == "a":
    # code
elif select == "s": 
    # code
elif select == "x": 
    return
else:
    print("some text")

# *** This line is executed unless select is "x" ***
```

However in your code, the `print` is **always** executed unless `select` is "x".  Also if `select` is "a" it is tested again for "s" and "x".  The extra tests probably won't be a big overhead in this case, but if `select` was a complex object then the comparison (which involves a method call) could be significant.

```
select = input("Enter 'a' to add, 's' to subtract, 'x' to exit: ")
if select == "a":
    # code
if select == "s": 
    # code
if select == "x": 
    return

# *** This line is executed unless select is "x" ***
print("some text")
```

Unless, that is, you have multiple `return` statements in your code.  It is generally considered good practice to only `return` from one point in a function.  The reason is that this makes the code easier to follow and maintain, and much easier to debug.

Don't get fixated on "wasting" one line of code.  Extra lines are not necessarily less efficient, the time taken on compilation is trivial.  In this case the code with more lines is actually more efficient because of fewer tests at runtime.  Python is not parsed and executed line-by-line like a shell (e.g. bash).  It is far more important that your code is easy to maintain.